# How to make this code simpler at JQuery?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a code like that:

```
  $('#messageList').change(function() {
     var id = $("#messageList option:selected").val();
     if(id <= 0) {
        $('#updatemessage').hide();
        $('#addmessage').show();
     } else {
        $('#updatemessage').show();
        $('#addmessage').hide();
     }
  });
```

Can I use anything else to make my code shorter for example toggle like functions at JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a bit more universal approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/DnP8s/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#messageList').change(function() {
  var doAdd = $(this).find("option:selected").val() <= 0;
  $('#updatemessage').toggle(!doAdd);
  $('#addmessage').toggle(doAdd);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// cache variables
var updatemessage = $('#updatemessage');
var addmessage= $('#addmessage');
var list = $('#messageList');

// toggle messages 
list.change(function() {
 var id = list.find("option:selected").val();
 updatemessage.toggle(id > 0);
 addmessage.toggle(id <= 0);
});
```

Comment: Since you did the caching which I like, try doing this: `var id=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`. Why would you use .find when you actually have the index? :D